# Encryption issue with GPG and PGP

Tags: gpg

I want to know whether GPG or PGP are able to encrypt and decrypt a file with special and international characters in it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, gpg can encrypt and decrypt any file.

Comment: But i have read somewhere gpg fails to do that. 
My requirement is we are using some cryptor tool which uses public key cryptography algo to encrypt and decrypt the file .The problem here is it is not able to encrypt or decrypt the file properly which has special characters in it (forbidden character like ', ", &, \, /, -).

Comment: https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/issue1472